# Can you create a bar graph with just the bars in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am needing to create a bar graph in flutter that is rather basic. Like the graph in the image. I really just need a graph that has the bars, not much extra. Using charts_flutter I can create graphs, but nothing that is like what I am looking for. Does anyone know of a way using charts_flutter or even another package? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, use these options:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.BarChart(
      seriesList,
      animate: animate,

      /// Assign a custom style for the measure axis.
      ///
      /// The NoneRenderSpec can still draw an axis line with
      /// showAxisLine=true.
      primaryMeasureAxis:
          new charts.NumericAxisSpec(renderSpec: new charts.NoneRenderSpec()),

      /// This is an OrdinalAxisSpec to match up with BarChart's default
      /// ordinal domain axis (use NumericAxisSpec or DateTimeAxisSpec for
      /// other charts).
      domainAxis: new charts.OrdinalAxisSpec(
          // Make sure that we draw the domain axis line.
          showAxisLine: true,
          // But don't draw anything else.
          renderSpec: new charts.NoneRenderSpec()),
    );
  }
```

this is from https://github.com/google/charts/blob/master/charts_flutter/example/lib/axes/hidden_ticks_and_labels_axis.dart, you can find many other examples there.